# How to create dev/staging/production environments

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an Xcode project that works in a development environment (using the computer as a local host), staging environment (a specific endpoint on a server), and a production environment (another specific server endpoint). I have found a few different tutorials about how to set this up. Some solutions suggest creating different target, some suggest creating different configurations. What is the most effective way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571454/ios-best-way-to-manage-development-testing-and-production-builds-with-differe/35572333. This link is Objective C based, but your tags specify swift. Similar concept though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the steps to create different schemes

1. Select the target
2. Create new scheme and give specific name to scheme (Dev,Staging,Prod,Debug)

i have attached screen shot for your reference

[Sample Screen Shot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQNSv.png)

[image]

if you want to set different url for different schemes then do the following steps:

1.Go to Build Setting

2.Go to user defined section

3.Create macros and specify urls for each environment

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Duplicate your current project Target and rename like DEV/QA/PROD.

**2.** Add New Environment.plist into your project. Structure of Environment.plist will be like below.[image]

**3.** In your service class add method to fetch baseURL according to your target settings. E.g Code:

> ```
> NSURL* environmentsURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Environments" withExtension:@"plist"];
> NSDictionary* environments = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:environmentsURL];
> NSString* currentEnvironment = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"Environment"];
> NSString* keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.baseURL", currentEnvironment];
> NSString *baseUrlString = [environments valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
> ```