# Best way to Test the "API_BASE_URL" In Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

Last month, I look a very good question:

> Best way to Manage Development, Testing, and Production builds with
> different settings and name

I used an answer which link is https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572333/4952106.

Now, I have a question.

> Best way to  Test the "API_BASE_URL" in Xcode with
> different settings and name

I thought about this question for a few minutes.

Can I achieve this by using different Unit test files for different `schemes`?

`MyApp_Dev_Environment_Unit_test` for scheme "MyApp_Dev" to test the

`API_BASE_URL` for `dev_api_url`

`MyApp_Staging_Environment_Unit_test` for scheme "MyApp_Staging" to test the

`API_BASE_URL` for `staging_api_url`

Comment: Yes, you can set different settings with different schemes. Seems you already know the answer.

Comment: I don't know how to do it step by step. I need a  website or a document.

Comment: Google's 1st search result: https://shockoe.com/ideas/development/how-to-setup-configurations-and-schemes-in-xcode/

Comment: Thanks. I don't see some information about unit tests with different schemes. Maybe my question doesn't descript clearly.